# Returning in a Scala For loop

Tags: scala, for-loop, return, scala-2.10

I am new to Scala so trying to do the simple thing first.

I wrote a method which is below.

```
//Given a list of numbers find the first number that is a multiple of 7
  def FindFirstMultiple(input: List[Int]) : Int  = {   
    for (
        i <- input        
        if (i % 7 == 0)
       ) 
      return i        
  }
```

This method gives error

```
type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required: Int
```

I am not able to comprehend this. When I don't have a return type and just print the values, it works fine.
Also, Why does the error squiggly hover over  `i <- input`. I think the Scala compiler is trying to tell me something, and I just can't understand it. What would be the cause of this error ?

Comment: While Scala does have the `return` keyword, it is rarely advisable (and, I daresay, never idiomatic Scala) to use it.

Comment: I still don't see the need to downvote.... People don't write idiomatic javascript/clojure or any other language in the questions they ask, then does that mean we should downvote every question ?

Comment: I did not down-vote the question. I think it's a perfectly valid question. I agree, we're here to guide questioners towards good Scala code, not punish them for not already having learned one thing or another about Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` in Scala is not a `for loop`, in fact it's not a loop at all. It's a syntactic sugar for map and flatMap and other monadic goodies. Monads are very useful in functional programming, i recommend invest some time learning them; you can start at http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2007/09/monads-are-elephants-part-1.html , follow the whole series. 
Thanks to the wonderful Mr James Iry.

If you just want the first item that matches your query, try this

```
val findFirst:Option[Int] = input.find(i => i % 7 == 0)
```

Posible values for `findFirst` are

1. Some(n)  if something was found, where n is the Int found
2. None  if nothing was found

Comment: def FindFirstMultiple(input: List[Int]) : Int  = { input.find(i => i % 7 == 0).getOrElse(0) }

Comment: Yes this would work. But how would you accomplish the same with a for loop ?

Comment: Scala does not have for loops.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run this with a for loop you need to also add a return  0 
as in

```
def FindFirstMultiple(input: List[Int]) : Int  = {   
    for ( i <- input if (i % 7 == 0)) return i 
    0       
  }
```

The end value is needed as the for itself doesn't return anything when the if isn't satisfied.

As user1779032 suggested a better way is

```
def FindFirstMultiple(input: List[Int]) = input.find(i => i % 7 == 0).getOrElse(0)
```